# Proposal for Mathematics Learning, Studying, and Education

Tags: discussion, area51

In view of [Forum for Chatty Math Education Questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12470/forum-for-chatty-math-education-questions), I thought to create this proposal. I'd appreciate your support and contributions. Please allow me to introduce it here and let me know otherwise.

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64216/mathematics-learning-studying-and-education

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea. I guess people tend to stick in a few stacks at a time (It's annoying to read questions on a lot of sites).

Comment: @PristineKavalostka I don't see why it's a bad idea to make this SE just because not everyone will come...

Comment: @PristineKavalostka - the main site has such incredible volume, a new site for educators won't be a loss. And will help avoid off-topic closure.

Answer (score 13):

This is an excellent idea!  For those not familiar with the area51 process, here's how you can help get this site off the ground:

1. Go to the site and click on "follow" in the upper left.  The site needs at least 60 followers to proceed to the next phase of the creation process.
2. **Upvote five of the questions**, and perhaps ask a few questions of your own.  The site needs at least 40 proposed questions with at least 10 upvotes each to proceed to the next phase of the creation process.
3. Comment on the merits of the questions, and join the discussion about the definition of the site.

See the [Area 51 FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) for more information on the Stack Exchange site creation process.

**Update:** Only 11 more followers are needed!  If you do follow, please take a minute to upvote five of the questions.

Comment: **Uppdate:** Only $1$ more follower and $23$ more questions with a score of $10$ or more are needed!

Answer (score 1):

The [proposal at Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64216/mathematics-educators) has attracted over 200 people who are interested in discussing mathematics education. The beta is going to start soon, and committed users are going to be invited in the private beta.

If you're interested in joining the beta, you can (as of now) commit to get invited.

Answer (score 0):

As an outsider (of the math world) looking in, one of the things that  makes learning about math so appealing is how eager insiders are to teach it to outsiders.

The teaching math Q&As significantly contribute to this stack's culture. Personally, whenever I've read a teaching thread, I've also been affected by how passionate the people here are about teaching math. I suspect that those threads go a long way in setting the tone for this stack. I think it could be a mistake to create a separate stack for them.

Comment: The proposed mathematics education Stack Exchange is not meant to teach math, but is meant to answer questions about *how* to teach math.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Yes, I know. What I meant was that in those threads, there's a certain positive energy and excitement about teaching math; I find it infectious, perhaps others do too. If they do, then it contributes to the overall positive energy and excitement that people in math.se have for teaching math. If positive energy and excitement about teaching math makes for better math teachers, and if the purpose of math.se is to facilitate math teaching, then perhaps having those threads in this stack furthers the purpose of this stack.